# SharePoint 2013 Access-Control-Allow-Origin duplicate headers

Tags: sharepoint, iis, cors

I wanted to add Access-Control-Allow-Origin for [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), but after adding HTTP Response Header on IIS, i am getting 2 http headers for Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

IIS Settings:

[image: IIS Settings]

Dev tools:

[image: Chrome Dev Tools]

I tried looking through stackoverflow, msdn, but i don't think much people faced this issue, can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Disable Request Management Service from all the web servers and the issue will go away

Use the PS below if you want to do it for the all the servers

Get-SPServiceInstance | where {$*.TypeName -match "Request Management"} | % { Stop-SPServiceInstance -Identity $*.id  -Confirm:$false }

Keep Running the below line to make sure the status is disabled for all the instances

Get-SPServiceInstance | where {$_.TypeName -match "Request Management"}  | ft -AutoSize

Once all are in disabled state, proceed with testing.